# Loop to simulate hierarchical clustering R

Tags: r, loops, hierarchical-clustering

I've used the `Vectorize` function to create a loop for a Kolmogorov Smirnov test for a 50x50 data set and made it output the p-values in a 50x50 matrix. And then stored these p-values as a distance object. Apply hierarchical clustering and store it as a dendrogram object. I repeat this again and then find the cophenetic correlation between them. The code below outputs a 2x2 matrix.

```
mat1 <- outer(1:50, 1:50, Vectorize(function(i,j)
          {ks.boot(as.numeric(rep(seq(0,14,1),as.vector(data[i,]))),
                   as.numeric(rep(seq(0,14,1),as.vector(data[j,]))),nboots=100)                   
                   $ks.boot.pvalue}))
rownames(mat) <- data2[, 1]
d1=as.dist(as.matrix(1-mat))
hcr1 <- hclust(d,method = "complete")
dend1 <- as.dendrogram(hcr)

mat2 <- outer(1:50, 1:50, Vectorize(function(i,j)
          {ks.boot(as.numeric(rep(seq(0,14,1),as.vector(data[i,]))),
                   as.numeric(rep(seq(0,14,1),as.vector(data[j,]))),nboots=100)                   
                   $ks.boot.pvalue}))
rownames(mat) <- data2[, 1]
d2=as.dist(as.matrix(1-mat))
hcr2 <- hclust(d,method = "complete")
dend2 <- as.dendrogram(hcr)

dendy <- dendlist(dend1,dend2)
cor <- cor.dendlist(dendy1)
cor1
```

So what I'm after is a for loop to simulate to obtain dend1,dend2,....,dend100. Store this into

```
dendy <- dendlist(dend1,dend2,...,dend100)
```

Comment: Could you specify your problem?

Comment: I have repeated the process once by copying and pasting the same code but changing the variable names. i.e mat1 & mat2, d1 &d2. Instead of copying this 100 times mat1,mat2,.....,mat100 I'd like to put it into a loop, calculate the p values 100 times and then use the procedure I stated and finally output a 100x100 matrix of the cophenetic correlations between each simulation

Comment: You just want to repeat the process a hundred times, changing nothing within the code?

Comment: Yes, I'm fairly new to loops in R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want a list with 100 `dend`, wrap the relevant code in a custom function without arguments, then `lapply` it 100 times:

```
FOO <- function(...){
  mat1 <- outer(1:50, 1:50, Vectorize(function(i,j)
  {ks.boot(as.numeric(rep(seq(0,14,1),as.vector(data[i,]))),
           as.numeric(rep(seq(0,14,1),as.vector(data[j,]))),nboots=100)                   
    $ks.boot.pvalue}))
  rownames(mat) <- data2[, 1]
  d1=as.dist(as.matrix(1-mat))
  hcr <- hclust(d,method = "complete")
  as.dendrogram(hcr)
}

dendy <- lapply(1:100, FOO)
```

Comment: I'm getting this error when I run dendy:  
Error in rep(seq(0, 14, 1), as.vector(test[i, ])) : 
  invalid 'times' argument

Comment: Got it to work, simple mistake that needed correction. Thanks!